# Choosing which variables to normalize while applying logistic regression

Tags: neural-network, logistic-regression, data-science

Suppose a dataset comprises independent variables that are continuous and binary variables. Usually the label/outcome column is converted to a one hot vector, whereas continuous variables can be normalized. But what needs to be applied for binary variables.

```
AGE       RACE  GENDER  NEURO   EMOT
15.95346    0    0       3       1
14.57084    1    1       0       0
15.8193     1    0       0       0
15.59754    0    1       0       0
```

How does this apply for logistic regression and neural networks?

Answer (score 1):

If the range of continuous value is small, encode it into a binary form and use each bit of that binary form as a predictor.
For example, number 2 = 10 in binary.
Therefore

predictor_bit_0 = 0

predictor_bit_1 = 1

Try and see if it works. Just to warn you, this method is very subjective and may or may not yield good results for your data. I'll keep you posted if I find a better solution

Comment: I dont think this answers my question, for continuous variables which differ quite largely between max and min, will need normalization. I have clearly mentioned what needs to be done for binary variables, (variables that have only 2 outcomes like a 0 or 1), do I just consume them or do i need to perform a similar operation like normalization?

Comment: Okay then you may want to reverse engineer the solution that I posted. Just combine the binary predictors into continuous predictors. For eg, for race=1, gender=0 and emot=1, x=1 : combine to form one binary number in which each bit represents one of the predictor. Your combined predictor for the above example would be 1011 (in binary) = 11 in decimal. You can use this predictor as it is or you can normalize it.